# How to grand runtime permissions with out requestPermissions() API

Tags: android, android-manifest, runtime-permissions

I would like to access "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" permission in a service.
The problem is as Service doesn't have UI, I can't show runtime dialog to user to allow runtime permission.
My question, is there a way to access this permission without asking runtime permission dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question, is there a way to access this permission without asking runtime permission dialog?

Fortunately, no, for privacy and security reasons.

> I can't show runtime dialog to user to allow runtime permission

Request the runtime permission from your UI before starting the service. Or, have the service display a `Notification` that can start your UI and request the permission.

Comment: I don't have any UI , its only a service.

Comment: @Narendar: Then you will need to tell the user to manually grant you the permission in Settings. I do not know *where* you will do that, since you have no UI.